# Matlab how to speed up array access

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, optimization

I'm running a simulation which keeps track of displacements of individual points (~1000-100,000 depending on geometry). When calculating the next time step acceleration, I need to access the current displacement.
The data is kept in a very large 2d array (1000x2) and is accessed with the following line:

```
eta = U2(connect(2:neib+1,i),:) - onearray*U2(i,:);
```

U2 is the displacement array, connect is a 2d array (61x1000) filled with integers. This line is run for each point and is the bottleneck, taking ~33% of the total compute time.

So my question is how can I speed up this line? I'm guessing the slowness has to do with accessing so many points in the array, so is there a way to decrease access time?

Edit: neib is an integer from 9 to 61 which keeps track of non-zero rows in connect. i is the iteration number, from 1 to number of points. Onearray = ones(neib,1) pre-allocated to reduce time.

Here's the entire loop around it:

```
for ii=1:nnodes     % #for each node (nodes are points)
    neib = connect(1,ii);
    onearray = ones(neib,1);
    eta= U2(connect(2:neib+1,ii),:) - onearray*U2(ii,:);   % #calculates stretch of bonds and subtracts stretch of node
    if eta == 0
        continue
    end
    xi=xiall(2:neib+1,:,ii);    % #gets vector distance for all horpts for node 'i' (2:total # of horpts+1,all,node)
    od=odall(2:neib+1,ii);     % #gets magnitude for all horpts for node 'i' (2:total # of horpts+1,all,node)

    cp=xi+eta;  % #adds stretch to (x-x') (cp is the current relative position vector from node to each bond)
    cd = sqrt(cp(:,1).^2 + cp(:,2).^2); % #cd (vector) is the new radii from node to horpts
    s=cd./od-1;     % #strain (by definition)

    f=C*s./cd*A;    % #calculates unit force density function
    UD(ii,:)=UD(ii,:)+sum([f f].*cp); % #adding force density function to equation of motion

end
```

Comment: Can you give us more insight on what the parameters in that line are for?  I can't suggest anything without knowing what the purpose of each of them are for.  Specifically, what is `neib`? Also, what is the purpose of `i`? Is this the iteration number?

Comment: neib is an integer from 9 to 61 which keeps track of non-zero rows in connect. i is the iteration number, from 1 to number of points. Onearray = ones(neib,1) pre-allocated to reduce time.

Comment: So if I'm understanding your problem properly, do the results from the current iteration rely on any results from the previous iteration?  Do you know all of the values of `neib` before hand, or is this dynamically computed at each iteration?

Comment: all values of neib are known beforehand. Everything in this line is static, except for the size of onearray. In fact, the element of connect(1,i) is where neib is stored.

Comment: In old Matlab versions it seems that using `i` as a variable name can slow things down (see comments to [this answer, or see [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17723167/2586922)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14790765/2586922)). Try changing that name and see if it helps

Comment: divide the structure into parts that fit into cache of cpu,gpu.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - You probably are unaware with how MATLAB works.  If you want access to the GPU, you would need to use the `gpuArray` structure in MATLAB and MATLAB only supports nVidia GPUs for computation.  Unless the OP has a nVidia card, this option won't work.  Also, judging from the context of the OP's problem, vectorization can surely be achieved which doesn't require any GPU acceleration.  I don't have the time to write an answer now as I'm at work, but I do have a couple of ideas that I want to try later tonight.

Comment: Could you supply more of the loop that surrounds this line?  I suspect the answer to speeding up this line is to vectorize the entire loop, or at least this portion of it.

Comment: surrounding code added to original post